# Retrieving data from firebase to google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase-realtime-database

I am making an app which downloads LatLngs from firebase and shows them as markers in `google maps API`, users can add new `LatLngs`.

In my database I also have the pricepoint and types of `markers`. In the main screen the user can choose what types of marker he wants to see on the map.

So my application does something like this:

```
locations.orderByChild(pricepoint).equalTo(choosenPricepoint);
```

and then I check programmatically if types match those chosen by the user

```
int type = Integer.parseInt(locations.child("restaurantType").getValue().toString();
if(type == funCode||  type == runingCode|| type == sportsCode
{
   mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(snapshot.getLatlng);
}
```

And it works fine with 250 records, but I'm expecting over 10,000 of them in my database so I am worried that it will be too slow.

I don't know if showing markers only where user's maps camera is and deleting other will be faster. What do you suggest?

Comment: Do you need to show markers on cpecific area or all over the map?

Comment: Now i show markers all over the map, but i think that it would also be okay if user would have to choose city in which he want's to see those markers.

Comment: Because right now it seem's like it would realy slow down the application, am I right? I don't know but showing 10,000 markers at once seems like a realy bad idea, because i think it might use a lot of memory.

Comment: Right,so you can show some on specific area and while user moving on the map,you can download more locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [GeoFire](https://github.com/firebase/geofire) , a firebase library that uses GeoHashes to merge lat+lon into a single property.That way you can do the distance filtering directly on the database.

You should have 2 entries in firebase database,one for setting your object location and one for setting your object with its fields.

[image]

As you can see they have the same `id`.So first you are queriing for nearby object by GeoFire in `geo_data` entry,and you will get the ids of the object which are nearby,then you can retreive object with its properties directly from database using the `ids` in my case in `user_data` entry

Comment: Okay, I am going to learn geofire, but I want to ask in advance, is there any way to send some additional data to firebase with geolocation using geofire?

Comment: I will edit the answer now and will explain how I am using it.

Comment: Okay, that's what I thought about, thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome,if there would be some additional questions feel free to ask here, I will try to help ;)